# Can I search and replace in a Notepad++ macro?

Tags: notepad++, macros, find-and-replace

I'm trying to create a macro in Notepad++ that allows me to do a few standard Search & Replaces. I can get the macro to do everything (add lines, add characters) except search and replace.

I can't find the files to edit the macro manually.

**Has anyone ever succeeded creating a Macro in Notepad++ that performs Search and Replace?** How?

*PS: I'm not interested in other tools that can perform this - I know my way around perl, vi(m), UltraEdit, sed, awk myself - I was just wondering if Notepad++ could do this.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can, I just tried to record a new macro, did a search and replace and it successfully saved the action so when I played the macro, it did the same search and replace action.

I am not an expert at Notepad++ Macros, but I am guessing you are... I opened a random file and created a macro called test. It looked for a word called "snip" and replaced it with "blaa".

Opening up the `shortcuts.xml` file after closing Notepad++ reveals this new macro:

```
<Macro name="test" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="snip" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="blaa" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1608" sParam="" />
</Macro>
```

This is tested and works on my machine, I can manually modify this file and the changes get reflected and work in Notepad++.

Please note however, the `shortcuts.xml` file (located in your Appdata folder), only gets loaded and saved on opening/exiting Notepad++.

Comment: Thanks. I found the file, but recording still didn't work. I edited the file (not with N++ off course) and pasted your snipped. N++ recognized the macro but it didn't successfully replace anything - I guess it must be some unfulfilled dependency that prevents me from recording/playing.

Comment: All I have is Notepad++ no special addons (Installed from Ninite)... Make sure you are using the latest version - but if you can't get this to work, something may be wrong with your installation.

Comment: I was after a "find and replace in all documents" function and was able to successfully produce it with the sample code above, with two minor changes:  the `lParam` "768" above became "2" and the `lParam` "1608" became "1635".  Otherwise, it worked great!  (Notepad++ 5.9.2)

Comment: I'm using v7.6 and I was able to record a macro to do search and replace. It generated the same definition in `shortcuts.xml`.

However the macro didn't work until after I closed Notepad++ and re-opened the program. I looked the `shortcuts.xml` to replace what was recorded with your example, and discovered nothing new had been written to the file. Then I remembered your note about shortcuts only getting loaded and saved only when the program opens and closes. So thanks @WilliamHilsum for that super helpful tip. I might have abandoned the effort without it.

Answer (score 6):

I previously found that this didn't work for me either. But then I updated from Notepad++ 5.6.x to 5.9.8, and now I can record find-and-replacing just fine. Very nice!

Of course, manually editing `shortcuts.xml` after recording one is inevitable because there is no a macro editor, and you need super human concentration for recording a huge macro flawlessly. (Make sure all instances of Notepad++ are closed before editing that file.)

Answer (score 1):

I too did not find any macro editor (for manipulating text) on Notepad++ (though Notepad++ provides few inbuilt functions). But now there is a plugin available for creating macros on Notepad++. This plugin is called '**Python Script**' (with good documentation and samples) through which you can write any kind of macros since with this plugin, you almost have full control availble over editor and Notepad++ itself. If you have some basic knowledge on python you may start writing macros using this plugin (The documentation of this plugin itself covers some basic python syntax for beginners).

You can **search & replace** and perform almost any kind of operation as a macro using this plugin.

Here is the link for more information:
http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/