# Notepad++ Find and Replace Advice

Tags: notepad++, macros

I am using Notepad ++ (v6.5.1)

I need to edit a large text file and remove certain ASCII characters from it, some of these may not be in the file, some may be in multiple times.

These are:  !”£$%^&*()_+=-€/.,#’;][?><~@:}{áéíóú

In the case of £ this needs replacing with GBP and also & needs replacing with "and"

What would be the easiest way to do this?  I need to amend multiple files daily so an easy way to replicate would be helpful, i.e. can I write a macro and use that etc?

Comment: yes, you can record a macro. Please have a look on notepad++'s help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I search and replace in a Notepad++ macro?](http://superuser.com/questions/223016/can-i-search-and-replace-in-a-notepad-macro)